# How to implement a imagebrush size in android

Tags: android, imagebrush

I am new to android development. I have started implementing paint related app. In that i wanted the user to select the brush size which is shown on a bar. I mean on pressing '+' button it should increase the brush size and move slightly on the bar and vice versa on pressing '-' button. Is there any API which I can use like the one in iPhone(I heard about spinner API)? I have not found any such API on the net.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
-Pratima

Answer (score 0):

What's about [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html)?
For example

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      
            params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, RemindButton.getId());
            WidthBar = new SeekBar(this);
            WidthBar.setMax(70);
            WidthBar.setProgress(15);
            WidthBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    if (fromUser)
                    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(progress); //Change StrokeWidth       
                }
            });
 LL.addView(WidthBar,params3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void addStrokeWidth(Paint paint, int width) {
        paint.strokeWidth += width
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**